# Terraform - Updating S3 Access Control: Question on replacing acl with grant

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, acl, terraform-provider-aws

I have an S3 bucket which is used as Access logging bucket.

Here is my current module and resource TF code for that:

```
module "access_logging_bucket" {
    source = "../../resources/s3_bucket"
    environment = "${var.environment}"
    region = "${var.region}"
    acl = "log-delivery-write"

    encryption_key_alias = "alias/ab-data-key"

    name = "access-logging"
    name_tag = "Access logging bucket"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "default" {
    bucket = "ab-${var.environment}-${var.name}-${random_id.bucket_suffix.hex}"
    acl = "${var.acl}"

    depends_on = [data.template_file.dependencies]

    tags = {
        name = "${var.name_tag}"
        . . .
    }

    lifecycle {
        ignore_changes = [ "server_side_encryption_configuration" ]
    }
}
```

The default value of variable *acl* is `variable "acl" { default = "private" }` in my case. And also as stated in [Terraform S3 bucket attribute reference doc](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket#attributes-reference).

And for this bucket it is set to `log-delivery-write`.

I want to update it to add following *grants* and remove *acl* as they conflict with each other:

```
grant {
    permissions = ["READ_ACP", "WRITE"]
    type = "Group"
    uri = "http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/s3/LogDelivery"
}
grant {
    id = data.aws_canonical_user_id.current.id
    permissions = ["FULL_CONTROL"]
    type = "CanonicalUser"
}
```

**My Questions are:**

1. Is removing the `acl` attribute and adding the above mentioned `grants` still maintain the correct access control for the bucket. i.e. is that grant configuration still good to have this as an Access Logging bucket.
2. If I remove the acl from the resource config, it will make it `private` which is the default value. Is that the correct thing to do or should it be made null or something?

On checking some documentation for `Log Delivery group` found this which leads me to think I can go ahead with replacing the *acl* with the *grants* I mentioned:

> Log Delivery group – Represented by
> http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/s3/LogDelivery . WRITE permission on a
> bucket enables this group to write server access logs (see Amazon S3
> server access logging) to the bucket. When using ACLs, a grantee can
> be an AWS account or one of the predefined Amazon S3 groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [grant-log-delivery-permissions-general](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/enable-logging-programming.html#grant-log-delivery-permissions-general) documentation, I went ahead and ran the *terraform apply*.

On first run it set the `Bucket owner` permission correctly but removed the `S3 log delivery group`. So, I ran the `terraform plan` again and it showed the following acl grant differences. I am thinking it's most likely that it first updated the `acl` value which removed the grant for `log delivery group`.

Thus I re-ran the `terraform apply` and it worked fine and corrected the *log delivery group* as well.

```
  # module.buckets.module.access_logging_bucket.aws_s3_bucket.default will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_s3_bucket" "default" {
        acl                         = "private"
        bucket                      = "ml-mxs-stage-access-logging-9d8e94ff"
        force_destroy               = false
        . . .
        tags                        = {
            "name"                                = "Access logging bucket"
            . . .
        }

      + grant {
          + permissions = [
              + "READ_ACP",
              + "WRITE",
            ]
          + type        = "Group"
          + uri         = "http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/s3/LogDelivery"
        }
      + grant {
          + id          = "ID_VALUE"
          + permissions = [
              + "FULL_CONTROL",
            ]
          + type        = "CanonicalUser"
        }
        . . .
    }

Plan: 0 to add, 1 to change, 0 to destroy.
```