# How do you create IAM roles in Terraform that do not already exist?

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

You clicked on this question thinking the answer would obviously just be, "Run `terraform apply`, duh," didn't you? Simple, right? Well, my friend, nothing is ever simple XD

When I run [`list-roles`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/list-roles.html) using `aws iam list-roles --query "Roles[].RoleName"`, the output confirms that the `RoleName` in question does not exist.

When I run `aws iam get-role --role-name [RoleName]` the output is.

```
An error occurred (NoSuchEntity) when calling the GetRole operation: The role with name [RoleName] cannot be found.
```

When I look in the AWS console, I cannot see the `RoleName` in question.

When I run `terraform apply` the output is,

```
Error: Error creating IAM Role [RoleName]: EntityAlreadyExists: Role with name [RoleName] already exists.
status code: 409, request id: ***
```

I have also tried importing the role into the state file using `terraform import aws_iam_role.RoleName RoleName` and it imports successfully. I am also able to review said statefile and confirm that the `RoleName` has indeed been created. When I then run the `terraform plan` it wants to create the same role anyway!

What could be causing terraform to juggle Schrodinger's IAM role?? Can you point me in the right direction on how to get out of this purgatory?

**NB**

- I am using Terraform v0.12.31.
- I have seen [Terraform (0.12.29) import not working as expected; import succeeded but plan shows destroy & recreate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64758624/terraform-0-12-29-import-not-working-as-expected-import-succeeded-but-plan-sh) but the role is not having a forced replacement, terraform wants to create it new.
- resource code is as follows.

main.tf

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "[RoleName]" {
  name               = "[RoleName]-${var.aws_region}"
  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

Comment: What does `aws iam get-role` show? How did you import the role, what is your terraform code for the role? Do the terraform commands run as the same user as the `aws iam` calls?

Comment: Yes, terraform commands are run as the same user. Description edited to answer other questions.

Comment: I would then see what happens if you try to create the role in the cli or in the console and then contact AWS support.

Comment: I *was* able to create the same RoleName using the console.

Comment: I then deleted the role that I had just created an ran another plan but I *still* get 409! Confuzled...

Comment: Delete the IAM role (pretending it exists, even it does not) from AWS CLI and try again `aws iam delete-role --role-name [RoleName]`